# Threading and server-client application: trying to increase a counter from multiple threads

Tags: python

I have coded a server in Python. This server is listening in a port and, whenever a new client connects, it creates a new thread that will manage communications with this client (the server will go back to accept new incoming connections):

```
import socket
import select
import thread
import sys
import time


class Server(object):
    def __init__(self, host, port):

        self.host = host
        self.port = port

        # Sockets creation
        self.sck = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

        self.i = 0

    def open(self):
        try:
            self.sck.bind((self.host, self.port))
            # Set maximum number of queued connections to 5
            self.sck.listen(5)
        except socket.error, (errno, msg):
            print 'Error: ' + str(errno) + ' - ' + str(msg)
            sys.exit(1)

    def close(self):
        self.sck.close()

    def loop(self):
        while True:
            conn, addr = self.sck.accept()
            thread.start_new_thread(self.handle, (conn, ))
            print 'Connected with ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1])

    def run(self):
        self.open()
        self.loop()
        self.close()

    def handle(self, conn):
        conn.send('Welcome! Type something and hit enter.\n')
        while True:
            data = conn.recv(1024)
            if not data:
                break
            if data == 'count\n':
                conn.send(str(self.i) + '\n')
            else:
                self.i += 1
        conn.close()

test = Server('localhost', 2020)
test.run()
```

Notice the `Server` class has a variable `self.i`, which is returned when a client sends the message `count\n`; if the message is something different, this variable will be incremented. This seems to work well when I manually connect to the server with `ncat` (connecting with multiple clients from multiple terminals works well too):

```
[terminal 1]$ ncat localhost 2020
Welcome! Type something and hit enter.

[terminal 2]$ ncat localhost 2020
Welcome! Type something and hit enter.

[terminal 1]$ count
0
foo
count
1

[terminal 2]$ count
1
qwer
asdf

[terminal 1]$ count
3
```

The problem comes when I try to send a lot of messages as fast as possible. What I would like to do is to be able to connect with, in example, `10` clients (`10` threads), and send at the same time `1000` messages from each thread. Then, when I look at the variable `self.i` I would like it to be `10 * 1000 = 10000`.

I must be doing something wrong, or I may be missing some point, as this (incrementing `self.i` when many messages are received continuously/fast) does not work even with a single client/thread.

I have tried with `ncat` with no success:

```
seq 1000 | ncat localhost 2020
```

And with a Python client with no success either:

```
import socket
import select
import thread
import sys
import time


class Client(object):
    def __init__(self, host, port):
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.sck = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    def open(self):
        try:
            self.sck.connect((self.host, self.port))
        except socket.error, (errno, msg):
            print 'Error: ' + str(errno) + ' - ' + str(msg)
            sys.exit(1)

    def close(self):
        self.sck.close()

    def loop(self):
        for i in range(1000):
            self.sck.send(str(i))

    def run(self):
        self.open()
        self.loop()
        self.close()

test = Client('localhost', 2020)
test.run()
```

In both cases, `self.i` is incremented, but very little, not as expected.

What am I doing wrong? Do I have to wait for a response/confirmation from the server before sending the next message? Maybe this approach is incorrect and threads should not be modifying the server's `self.i` variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nearly every beginner to socket programming does the same mistake, because 99% of all tutorials on internet are wrong at this point.

Your problem is the line

```
data = conn.recv(1024)
```

TCP is a streaming protocol. That means, `data` can contain up to 1024 bytes or less. Even only 1 byte is possible, and the command 'count' could be split into 5 separate `recv` calls. In your case it is the other way round. One `recv` receives many commands, up to 1024 bytes. So many your counter is much less than expected.

Therefore you have to parse the incoming stream into messages, which are in your case separated by newline-character:

```
def handle_message(self, conn, message):
    if data == 'count':
        conn.sendall('%i\n' % self.i)
    else:
        self.i += 1

def handle(self, conn):
    conn.sendall('Welcome! Type something and hit enter.\n')
    buf = ''
    while True:
        data = conn.recv(1024)
        buf += data
        while '\n' in buf:
            message, buf = buf.split('\n',1)
            self.handle_message(conn, message)
        if not data:
            break
    conn.close()
```

To send data always us `sendall`.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense to me. I was wondering how the server was splitting the messages I was sending and the answer is that it is not doing so, it is just receiving a stream of data and is up to you to parse all the information received. :-D Will try it soon. +1 for now. ;-)

Comment: Thank you. :-D Now I will have a look at how to lock the variable, as suggested by Lasse V. Karlsen, because now some of the messages are lost when multiple clients are sending messages at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're not locking access to that variable.

Basically, this statement:

```
self.i += 1
```

can be split into these distinct operations:

```
temp = self.i
temp = temp + 1
self.i = temp
```

If two threads manages to read the same `self.i` and continue on their merry way you've lost an increment.

In short, thread-safe code is not easy to write, but at least begin with locking around all shared state.

I don't know how to lock in Python, but you should find plenty of examples out on the web or here on SO.

Comment: But notice it does not work even with a single thread (only one client connected to the server). In this case, not locking the variable could be also the problem?

Comment: You need to explain then what you mean by not working because from your example it seems to work just fine, ie. the terminal example there. Are any of those numbers wrong? Or, if the "single thread" problem has a different example, perhaps post that?

Comment: Multiple threads work well, and incrementing the variable manually (notice ncat is launched and messages are written "by hand" in the first example) works well too. The problem is when trying to send a lot of messages fast. That, it does not work even with a single thread. Sorry if I didn't explain myself well.

Comment: You answer the second problem I've found with my code (when running multiple threads at the same time), so thank you! (+1)